# asp.net mvc create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have created a Create view.Now the thing is that I want to throw all the fields from the create view into the data plus two other fields which are not on the view which are created date and created by .How will I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this sample code from [NerdDinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm), look at the comments:

```
// POST: /Dinners/Create

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {

        try {         
            // here you can add your other fields:
            dinner.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            dinner.CreatedBy = LoggedUserId; // you have to figure out how to get this

            dinnerRepository.Add(dinner);
            dinnerRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new {id = dinner.DinnerID });
        }
        catch {        
            ModelState.AddRuleViolations(dinner.GetRuleViolations());
        }
    }

    return View(dinner);
}
```